JasperReports 6.2.1 Retaining Textfield Text Value without default truncation
We are currently using Jasper Reports 6.2.1 due to the restrictions of the current tech stack we are working on. This report will only be exported to the Excel (xlsx) file format. For this report, we are encountering a problem of where a lengthy promo code description field that breaks after a certain length.
For this case, the description value stored in a database has the value of "This is an application loan promo of iabc where bla bla bla bla bla..." (up to 255 characters) In the test result, the description only shows up to "This is an application loan promo of iabc", the remainder of the text is truncated at the report side.
While it is known that have been similar issues reported previously, yet most of those reported are for older versions. I am still encountering this issue after adding the required text element properties including those that are excel-related, here's the source code that that particular textField that we had an issue on:
<textField textAdjust="StretchHeight" isBlankWhenNull="true">
   <reportElement style="Report Detail Text (center)" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" 
x="3540" y="0" width="120" height="15" uuid="a7942ae0-35bb-4fad-993e-d9ae9b18a46a">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="ea10b0cf-fed0-44b4-baac-d30078972526"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="false"/>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="false"/>
 </reportElement>
    <box>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
    </box>
        <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{promo_code} + "\n"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>

I have also experimented on adding a "\n" new line to this field at the text field expression, but it also does not work as well. The isStretchOverflow property is already deprecated.
What other alternatives and solutions can I look to show the entire description text? Wrapping can be considered, but as last resort. We prefer to have the entire description text shown in one line in excel file.
